# wxWidgets Widget for representing std::map?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm working on a level editor for my game engine, and I've run into a small problem. Game objects can have values associated with them, each value having a name and a value (yes, I know this is redundant, it came up repeatedly when getting everything set up). I need a widget that will allow me to represent a map of values (key being the name, obviously), but I can't seem to find any. Any suggestions?
Note: The values will ONLY be strings, due to the fact that this makes it easier to store and how simple it is to convert strings to booleans, integers, and floating points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a widget to view a std::map then I think [wxPropertyGrid](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_property_grid.html) should be what you want. It has a pretty extensive example under samples/propgrid in your wxWidgets install.

Comment: It's not part of 2.8.9 (the current release) but it is available separately. In 2.9.0 it's included.